# Search within PDF Files to Find a String

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I need to search within a pdf file to find a string.I know that itextsharp has this feature and i can use this code

```
public bool SearchPdfFile(string fileName, String searchText)
{
    /* technically speaking this should not happen, since "you" are calling it
       therefore this should be handled critically
        if (!File.Exists(fileName)) return false; //original workflow
    */
    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found", fileName);

    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileName))
    {
        var strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            var currentPageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
            if (currentPageText.Contains(searchText))
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

But im using the itext under LGPL/MPL License (version 3.0/4.0) ,the newer version 5.0 is only free if I make my own software free under the AGPL. The class SimpleTextExtractionStrategy is undefined in this version of itext.Is there any alternative to do this using the old version of itext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDFClown.
A silly name, but it is quite a detailed and flexible PDF library. I've used it before. It is free under LGPL. http://pdfclown.org/about/#TheLicense

Example modified from the PDFClown website (their example is java)

```
File file = new File(myFilePath);

// Define the text pattern to look for!
String textRegEx = "rabbit";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(textRegEx, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

// Instantiate the extractor!
TextExtractor textExtractor = new TextExtractor(true, true);

for(final Page page : file.getDocument().getPages())
{
  // Extract the page text!
  Map<Rectangle2D,List<ITextString>> textStrings = textExtractor.extract(page);

  // Find the text pattern matches!
  final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(TextExtractor.toString(textStrings));
}
```

Updated for C#

```
    File file = new File(myFilePath);

    // Define the text pattern to look for!
    var pattern = new Regex("rabbit", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    // Instantiate the extractor!
    TextExtractor textExtractor = new TextExtractor(true, true);

    foreach (var page in file.Document.Pages)
    {
        // Extract the page text!
        var textStrings = textExtractor.Extract(page);

        // Find the text pattern matches!
        var matches = pattern.Matches(TextExtractor.ToString(textStrings));
    }
```

Comment: thanks .. can i use it to search for a string.Can you provide an example

Comment: Yes, you can. I'll update it with an example. This is pulled/modified from the PDFClown website, and its in Java, but the the procedure is the same for C#.

Comment: thanks a lot.I have seen your example,but how i can get the page number from the Matcher Object.

Comment: Matcher is just the java equivalent of Regex in .Net.
As to the page number, that example is iterating through the pages one at a time, so there you go.

Comment: sorry for accepting the answer late.. was busy with some other stuff.thanks

Comment: NW. Glad it worked out for you :)

Comment: I tried it today but Map and Matcher are undefined.

Comment: That example is in Java. Those are java classes. You would want to use `Dictionary` and `Regex` in C#.
I pulled that example off their website and they only had java. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: do you mind in editing the answer as this question is in c# tag,it would confuse people who are reading this in future.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. I can't at this moment, but I will.

Comment: @techno Updated to C# as promised. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Accepted your answer.

Comment: I get this exception: org.pdfclown.util.parsers.ParseException : ''name' table does NOT exist.' when the line var textStrings is reached.